# How to run Servlet on ipad

Tags: java, ios, ipad, servlets

heard that iphone/ipad does not support java. Is that true?
If yes then how do I run my Servlet on iPad?

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: I think of servlets as plug-ins that run inside a server shell.  What is there on an iPad that you want to have as a host for your servlet?

Comment: i have a servlet that handles requests and i want to run it on the ipad.

Comment: do you mean the webserver? if yes then apache tomcat

Comment: Right...so your bigger problem is that Tomcat doesn't run on an iPad.

Comment: yes...but following the below i guess i can run my servlet at some otehr location and access the link to that page from my safari browser in Ipad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. For running a servlet you'd need a Java web container on top of a JVM, and that's impossible since there is no Java support on any of the iOS devices.

If you really, really need to run a servlet-based application maybe you could do so in the cloud and access it from the iPad.

Answer (score 2):

While you cant run Servlets on iOS as java is not supported, you can always access a web application based on Servlets, that is hosted on a java supported platform, through a browser in your iPad

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation
(click on this box to dismiss) :(
i have only 11